# Reading Romanian baptismal record?

Tags: baptism-records, romania

I have a copy of baptism that belong to my great grandmother who immigrated here from Romania.

Is there anyone who can help me make sense of this document?

I am attaching a copy of this record.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!.The document is a Romanian Catholic baptismal certificate, all in Latin - pre printed and written parts, issued in 1901 for a child was born and baptized in 1874. This kind of certificate could have been issued before marriage or emigration. I think the place "Corona" is Brașov, then Kronstadt or Brassó, in Transylvania, Hungary.

Comment: @bgwiehle Can you make this into an answer, please, instead of answering in the comments? If you don't have time, just put your existing text into a answer and I can add resource links (the genealogical word lists at FamilySearch, etc.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The document is a Roman Catholic baptismal certificate, all in Latin - pre printed and written parts, issued in 1901 for a child was born and baptized in 1874. This kind of certificate could have been issued before marriage (as proof of baptism) or emigration (as identification).

Columns are

- sequential record number, for the year, part of the original record; volume info is in the line below "Baptisatorum" in the header
- officiant
- birth and baptism dates, given in numbers and written out in words, born 29th November 1874, baptized 13th December 1874
- residential address of the family, Bolonya #217, but street names have changed since then
- child's name, Vilhemina
- child's gender, not recorded, but the name was female
- religion, Roman Catholic
- parents, Joannes Péter and Rosa Varga. He was from in Szászfalu, Kézdi felső, Háromszék  megye, now Săsăuşi, part of Lunga in Covasna county, northeast of Brașov. His occupation "arcularius sodalis" (translation suggested in comments). She was 18 years old and from Csík-Rákos, Csík-szépvizi, Csík megye, now Racu, Harghita county
- godparents
- midwife
- observation, 1st gen. - possibly in reference to the fact that both parents were from elsewhere, but possible that Vilhemina was also their 1st child

Below

- place and date copy issued. "Corona" is Brașov, then Kronstadt or Brassó, in Transylvania, Hungary. "Baases" is likely the suburb, but not confirmed
- seal of the church (Sts Peter and Paul)
- administrator's signature

Other notes

- the stamp in the upper left is proof that the 1 Krone fee for the copy was paid
- some spots partially illegible due to tape stains; original or colour copy may be more legible
- Ancestry.com collection "[Romania, Vital Records from Selected Regions, 1607-1914](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/romaniagerchurchbooks/)" has images from the original church register; copy seems to be faithful to the original

Comment: arcularius sodalis: guild cabinetmaker

Comment: 1gen: primogenita "firstborn".